# What's the point using "git add <file>" if you can just use "git add ." everytime?

Tags: git

If I add say 2 new files. Is there any advantage to using the former over the latter? Or is it just useless syntax?

Comment: You don't want to commit useless files

Comment: You don't always want to commit every file that has changed.

Comment: Thanks guys. Flew over my head that.

Comment: You just haven't come across or thought of a use case. If you read the docs carefully it might help.

Comment: When you are under a sub directory, `git add .` adds only the files under and recursively under the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense in using a versioning system, if you always add everything and commit it like "add current changes".

I have seen this a lot, i have even seen one colleague setting up a cronjob, that does this automatically (so he ends up with hundreds of commits like "commit by crontab").

The purpose for a versioning system is to understand code changes. You want to be able to find errors, bugs and regressions based on single commits. You might also want to revert single changes. That's not possible, if you add everything always.

In my opinion it is even better to start using `git add --patch [path]` over `git add [path]`. It will consume little more time, but your commit history will be even better.

When developing a project in early stage, you often do more than 1 thing simultaneously. When committing your work-in-progress and using `git add --patch [path]`, you can select only the lines that belong to Feature-A and afterwards the lines for Feature-B. Of course you can develop features in branches, but in early stages I usually don't use heavy workflows.

If you dont like the typing, add the following snippet to your `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
ap = add --patch
```

Then you can simply type `git ap [path]`

By editing your commit manually, you can even commit a line partially (because 2 features required code changes in the same line).

Answer (score 0):

`git add <file>` allows you to add only a specific file. Imagine you did some changes on the config file of your project to enable a feature flag, or to change a DB setting. you probably don't want that change to be committed.